# Can I use the .name TLD on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I don't have a domain or company, so I'm thinking about using the .name TLD and my email address `jdoe@gmail.com` as the app package name in the manifest:

```
name.gmail.jdoe.coolapp
```

Is this good enough? Or am I better off using the TLD .com or .org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth it to get an own domain to use it as your package name. That way you have for sure a unique package name.

Moreover during upload to Google play they will want to know about the developer's website anyway and this will be publicly displayed

Also, Google Play won't allow the upload of package names that already exist in Google Play anyway. So you can just check in the store if someone uses the package already.

Comment: Website is not mandatory: "You must pick one support channel for your app: Website, Email, or Phone."

Comment: @Arthur ok, it is possible to just show email instead, but what I wanted to say is that it is not _recomended_, because it doesn't make a good impression to the users. Anyway, if you still don't want to have domain you can just search if someone uses your package name already and then just upload apk